# JMock HttpServletRequest set parameter

Tags: junit, jmock

How do I set parameters into my HttpServletRequest in JMock? I search around the Google, many are old and the methods deprecated. The official website is only telling me how to use the tools but it doesn't state how to set parameters for HttpServletRequest?

Please have some guides. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

found out the way now, just using new Expectations() syntax.

```
    context.checking(new Expectations() {{
        oneOf(req).getParameter("sitename"); will(returnValue(siteName));
        oneOf(req).getParameter("pagename"); will(returnValue(pageName));
        oneOf(req).getParameter("textcolor"); will(returnValue(textColor));
        oneOf(req).getParameter("buttoncolor"); will(returnValue(buttonColor));
        oneOf(req).getParameter("bordercolor"); will(returnValue(borderColor));
        oneOf(req).getParameter("subscribetext"); will(returnValue(subscribeText));
        oneOf(req).getParameter("unsubscribetext"); will(returnValue(unsubscribeText));
        allowing(req).getRequestDispatcher(result);
        allowing(req).getRequestURL();
    }});
```

Comment: First, it's better to use the allowing() clause for the parameters. That makes it clear that it's a query and won't break the test for irrelevant changes. Second, the allowing() clauses you do have will return default values (possibly null). Is that what you want? Third, what are you testing here? I tend to write helper objects that translate between text and the domain, and then use end-to-end tests to exercise the whole thing.